# How to get LookAt data from KML file in Java

Tags: java, kml, jak

There is a tag called LookAt in the kml file. as below:

```
<LookAt>
        <longitude>51.36863708496094</longitude>
        <latitude>35.7291434559867</latitude>
        <altitude>0</altitude>
        <heading>0</heading>
        <tilt>0</tilt>
        <range>0</range>
        <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
</LookAt>
```

I need to get the lat and long information of this tag.
I also use the jak library.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Call getAbstractView() method on placemark object using JAK API. Then use getLatitude() and getLongitude() methods in the LookAt object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer @CodeMonkey

The final answer is as follows:

```
Placemark placemark = (Placemark) folderFeature;
AbstractView abstractView = placemark.getAbstractView();
   if (abstractView != null) {
        if (abstractView instanceof LookAt) {
            LookAt lookAt = (LookAt) abstractView;
            lookAt.getLatitude();
            lookAt.getLongitude();
         }
    }
```